# How do I use the ID in one API to get info from another API in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So the API link www.api.com/id_list gives me IDs for some information in another API with link www.api.com/{id}.

I'm using Redux and I can get the id list however I am struggling to get the info needed via the IDs. It keeps telling me it's undefined.

So here's my code:

```
    export const EVENT_DETAIL = 'EVENT_DETAIL';

    export const eventDetail = (payload) => {
     return {
       type: EVENT_DETAIL,
       data: payload.data,
       index: payload.index
      };
    }  

    export const getDetail = (events, index) =>  {
        return function(dispatch) {
        const url = `${URL2}/${events}`;
        axios.get(url)
            .then (function (response) {
                   dispatch(eventDetail({
                   data: response.data.events,
                   index: index
               }))
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = () =>  {
        this.props.getDetail();
        console.log(this.props.getDetail())
       }
```

Any ideas why I can't get the information to show up?

Keep getting the follow error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:78)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getDetail action is returning a function that doesn't itself return anything - this is why undefined is logged to your console. Put a return infront of your axios.get function, this will your request in form of a promise.

```
return axios.get(url)
  .then (function (response) {
    dispatch(eventDetail({
      data: response.data.events,
      index: index
    }))
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

To get the response from your request, you need to wait for it to resolve. This is done by calling .then on the promise. Your componentDidMount would look like this.

```
componentDidMount = () =>  {
  this.props.getDetail()
  .then(res => console.log(res))
}
```

Comment: No this doesn't work - still getting the same error

Comment: Didn't see the image you attacthed. You're getting a 404 Not found error. This is a result of your network request not being able to find what your looking for. Could you do a logging the url your requesting from and make sure it's correct?